# Remove class from nav when sibling is clicked

Tags: javascript, class, if-statement, navigation

I've created a navigation that highlights whatever menu item is selected by adding an 'active' class. If you click the body it removes the active class from the menu item and starts over. It works as expected except when you click a sibling on the menu. The active class is added to the newly clicked menu item, but it also remains on the old one. I wrote code that is suppose to loop through all menu items to see if any of them have the 'active' class, remove the class and then add the 'active' class to the new selection. It's not working.

What am I doing wrong? Also is there any easier way to do this? I need to solve this with vanilla Javascript. I can't use jQuery.

// html

```
<ul class="nav-items">
   <li class="nav-item"></li>
   <li class="nav-item"></li>
   <li class="nav-item"></li>
   <li class="nav-item"></li>
   <li class="nav-item"></li>
   <li class="nav-item"></li>
   <li class="nav-item"></li>
</ul>
```

// js

```
if (navItems) {
    navItems.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var background = document.querySelector('.background');
        var callout = document.querySelectorAll('.background, .nav-close')
        console.log(e.target.closest('.nav-item'));

        if (background.style.display !== "block") {
            background.style.display = "block";
            for( let i = 0; i < e.target.closest('.nav-items').children.length; i++ ) {
                console.log(e.target.closest('.nav-items'));
                e.target.closest('.nav-item').classList.remove('active');
            }

            e.target.closest('.nav-item').classList.add('active');

            if (background.style.display === "block") {
                callout.forEach(function(elem) {
                    elem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                        background.style.display = "none";
                        console.log('target', e.target);
                        e.target.closest('.nav-item').classList.remove('active');
                    }); 
                });
            }

        } else {
            background.style.display = "none";
            e.target.closest('.nav-item').classList.remove('active');

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` is for ancestors not siblings. So `e.target.closest('.nav-item')` is only ever going to find itself as closest() finds either itself or an ancestor that matches that selector. Not any of it's sibling nav elements.

Meaning

```
e.target.closest('.nav-item').classList.remove('active')
```

Only ever tries to remove a class active from the currently clicked li.

You probably meant to use `e.target.closest('.nav-items').children` in your loop as a way of accessing the child li's, eg

```
var li = e.target.closest('.nav-items').children[i];
li.classList.remove('active');
```

But you don't really need a loop, unless you think you might end up with multiple active elements. You could just find the current active element by finding your closest ul element, and then from that find the `nav-item` that has class `active`, ie css class selector `.nav-item.active`

```
var parentUL = e.target.closest('.nav-items');
var current = parentUL.querySelector('.nav-item.active');
current.classList.remove('.active');
```

Comment: Hey Patrick, your explanation was helpful, but your solution didn't work. var current returns 'null'. It doesn't remove anything.

Comment: Then your UL element does not have an element with class `nav-item` and `active`

Comment: I kept my loop and added the following to it's body: 'e.target.closest('.nav-item').classList.remove('active')'. That seemed to do it. Thanks for your help.